# Google Chrome (not chromium) is crashing XFCE on startup. Where can I find some detailed logs of the issue?

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome

I'm using xubuntu 12.10 and every time I open Chrome, the desktop enviro crashes then automatically restarts, prompting me to log in again. This is the latest x86 .deb downloaded from Chrome's website.

I've tried both installing the .deb using the software package manager and using `sudo dpkg -i`, same issue for both, except that the package manager puts out an alert that says "This package is of bad quality", but doing a quick google search reveals that particular message is a bug in Chrome and it's safe to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

It had something to do with the video drivers. Updated video drivers and all was well. I updated to NVIDIA's latest beta driver (310.19) using a manual .run install